# How to update this firestore document field using cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im new to firebase, firestore and cloud functions. How do I update the this filed called "status" based on a field called "LastUpdatedAt"

```
exports.hello = functions.firestore.document("RealtimeData/{anyMachine}/Params/{anyParams}")
```

The field "LastUpdatedAt" is inside {anyParams}: It looks like

```
LastUpdatedAt: 1606844285038
```

After conversion from timestamp

```
LastUpdatedAt: 1/12/2020 23:8:5
```

How do I write a cloud function to compare this "LastUpdatedAt" with the present time and if the time difference is greater than 15 then the 'status' should be set to offline else it should be online.

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361437/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much

Comment: posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a single field in a document then first you should retrieve the document through document ID then you can perform the update function while specifying the field.

For more information you can refer  to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/#doc) and stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361437/15774176), where a brief description about node js SDK for Cloud Firestore has been discussed.